# Python Transpose Dataframe Rows as Column names and columns as rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a big df with multi x and y columns data. I want to interpolate y-data to common x-values and then transpose data with common x-values as column names and y-values as rows.

My code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x1':np.linspace(0,10,5),'y1':np.linspace(0,50,5),'x2':np.linspace(0,8,5),'y2':np.linspace(0,80,5),'x3':np.linspace(0,9,5),'y3':np.linspace(0,90,5)})

df = 
     x1    y1   x2    y2    x3    y3
0   0.0   0.0  0.0   0.0  0.00   0.0
1   2.5  12.5  2.0  20.0  2.25  22.5
2   5.0  25.0  4.0  40.0  4.50  45.0
3   7.5  37.5  6.0  60.0  6.75  67.5
4  10.0  50.0  8.0  80.0  9.00  90.0
```

The x-columns range from 0-10. I want to interpolate y-columns data for the same x 0-10 range. I am giving here an example

Expected answer:

```
df = 
     x    y1   y2   y3
0   0     0    0    0
1   2.0   10   20   25
2   4.0   20   40   50
3   6.0   30   60   75
4   8.0   40   80   100
# I want to transpose the x data as column names and y columns as rows data
df = 
      0.0   2.0    4.0   6.0   8.0
y1    0     10     20    30    40  
y2    0     20     40    60    80
y3    0     25     50    75    100
```

Comment: Shouldn't `y3` be `[0, 20, 40, 60, 80]` after interpolation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df.T` will transpose the dataframe.

Comment: This does not address the first part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([[i[1] for i in df.columns],
                                         [i[0] for i in df.columns]])

def y_over_x(d):
    d = d.droplevel(0, axis=1)
    return d['y']/d['x']

y = df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).apply(y_over_x).fillna(0).add_prefix('y')
x = pd.Series(np.arange(0, 10, 2), name='x')

df2 = pd.concat([x, y.mul(x, axis=0).astype(int)], axis=1)
```

output:

```
    x   y1  y2  y3
0   0   0   0   0
1   2   10  20  20
2   4   20  40  40
3   6   30  60  60
4   8   40  80  80
```

Then transpose:

```
df2.set_index('x').T
```

output:

```
x   0   2   4   6   8
y1  0  10  20  30  40
y2  0  20  40  60  80
y3  0  20  40  60  80
```